# Nesting a Progress Bar into a Combobox in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to nest a Progress bar into a combobox or the other way around. I want to be able to type into the combo box and hit a button and the progress bar shows the progress of the event, like in Windows Explorer.

EDIT: I need the code in Visual Basic.NET 3.5 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it, basically what I've done is:

1. Subclass ComboBox and add IsProgressVisible and ProgressValue dependency properties
2. Add a green rectangle the the ComboBox control template exactly behind the editable area
3. Bind the rectangle visibility to IsProgressVisible and the rectangle width (using a ScaleTransform) to ProgressValue

First the new control code:

```
public class ProgressCombo : ComboBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsProgressVisibleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsProgressVisible", typeof(bool), typeof(ProgressCombo));
    public bool IsProgressVisible
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsProgressVisibleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsProgressVisibleProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProgressValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ProgressValue", typeof(double), typeof(ProgressCombo));
    public double ProgressValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ProgressValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ProgressValueProperty, value); }
    }        
}
```

There's also a value converter we'll use:

```
public class FromPercentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double)value) / 100;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now take the combo box sample style from MSDN (.net 3.5 version, not 4) from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750638%28VS.90%29.aspx

Add an `xmlns:l` definition to your own assembly

Now change `<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="ComboBox">` to `<Style x:Key="{x:Type l:ProgressCombo}" TargetType="l:ProgressCombo">`

Change `<ControlTemplate TargetType="l:ComboBox">` To:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="l:ProgressCombo">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="Bool2Vis"/>
        <l:FromPercentConverter x:Key="FromPercent"/>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
```

Locate the line `<ContentPresenter` and add before it:

```
<Rectangle 
    Fill="LightGreen"
    Margin="3,3,23,3"
    Visibility="{TemplateBinding IsProgressVisible, Converter={StaticResource Bool2Vis}}">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ProgressValue, Converter={StaticResource FromPercent}}"/>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

And that's it

Comment: I need this code in VB.NET 3.5. When I converted the code using teleriks online code converter and pasted it into Visual Studio, I got all kinds of errors.

Comment: @muckdog12 - can't help you with VB syntax but the code is extreamly simple, the ProgressCombo class inherits from ComboBox and adds two dependency properties using the simplest boilerplate code IsProgressVisible of type Boolean and ProgressValue of type Double.  the FromPresentConverter class implements interface IValueConverter and in the Convert method retrns value/100 - you should be able to recreate those two classes using VB samples for dependency properties and value converters.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar sort of requirement for a different reason (i had a combo that was auto-populating after a network scan). See if this question & answer helps you: [WPF ComboBox - showing something different when no items are bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885991/wpf-combobox-showing-something-different-when-no-items-are-bound)

Comment: Thanks for the help but that is not quite what I need. It was a helpfull article though.